# Quelles seraient des variantes plus élégantes de la phrase (qui se décline en deux versions) citée dans les détails de la question?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, reformulation

> Les magasins à grande surface, comme la multinationale Walmart, qui donnent des salaires modiques à leurs employés, sont les auteurs mêmes du fléau (les vols internes en magasins) qui les afflige et contre lequel ils luttent.

> Les magasins à grande surface, comme la multinationale Walmart, du fait des maigres salaires qu’ils donnent à leurs employés, sont les auteurs mêmes du mal (les vols internes en magasin) qui les ronge et qu’ils cherchent à réprimer.

Comment: Dans la deuxième, les maigres salaires sont énoncés clairement comme la cause directe des vols internes, alors que dans la première formulation c'est un simple information donnée au passage, et c'est au lecteur de supposer si ça a un lien direct. Au-delà d'une question d'élégance, l'implication de la phrase est différente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Deux essais parmi un bien grand nombre d'autres possiblités qui seront toutes trouvées plus ou moins acceptables/élégantes*

1/ Les dirigeants des magasins à grande surface, comme la multinationale Walmart, parce qu'ils paient mal  leurs employés, sont eux-mêmes la cause  du vol en entreprise, un fléau qui les mine et qu'ils essaient d'enrayer sans succès.

2/ Les propriétaires des magasins à grande surface, comme la multinationale Walmart, du fait des maigres salaires qu’ils donnent à leurs employés, sont à la  source même d'un mal qui les ronge et qu'il leur est difficile d'éradiquer, c'est à dire le vol en interne.

Answer (score 1):

*Les grandes surfaces qui, comme Walmart, sous-paient leurs employés, sont elles-mêmes les instigatrices du fléau qui les afflige et contre lequel elles luttent.*

Answer (score 0):

Si on peut prendre un peu de liberté sur le texte, alors j'y vais aussi de ma proposition:

> Les grandes surfaces multinationales comme Walmart, du fait des faibles
> salaires qu'elles accordent à leurs employés, sont à l'origine même
> des phénomène du vol en entreprise qu'elles cherchent à réprimer, en
> créant des conditions propices au passage à l'acte.

PS on ne dit jamais "magasins à grande surface"